# htaccess redirect all traffic of a folder to other and include name as header

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i want to change my folder structure of my web app,

The current structure is

```
/websites
    .subdomain1
      .index.html
      .app
        .htaccess
        index.php
```

DNS:
http://subdomain1.website.com/  ->points to folder of subdomain1

now in current structure the php is located inside same folder, i want to move it out, problem is i need to redirect all requests to old directory that is not a file to be redirected, and include subdomain in header.

Example
Current API ENDPOINT

```
http://subdomain1.website.com/app/token
```

i want this request instead of going to /subdomain1/app/index.php , i want it to go to **/api/index.php** and include 'subdomain1' as a header.

so that the my folder structure would become

```
/website
  .subdomain1
    .index.html
/api
  index.php
```

and all traffic going to the old /app folder redirected to new folder with subdomain as a header.

current htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located? Also I don't see `api` folder in your directory structure

Comment: its inside app folder, api folder i want to create it @ root directory and redirect all traffic to it.

Comment: @anubhava i edited question to clarify. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your current .htaccess to this:

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /api/index.php [L]
```

Comment: can i include allies like '../' ? because the new index.php is located at ../../v1/api/index.php  will that works ?

Comment: Yes you can use `../` here OR else use full path like `/path/to/v1/api/index.php` in target